# Enderman won't leave my house but didn't attack me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm very new to minecraft & am playing in survival mode. The first few nights I noticed Enderman wandering near my base. I didn't know what he was so I just avoided him. Fast forward several days of playing; I was farming outside during the day & as I enter my house I see this shimmery thing floating around. I follow it & next thing I know this thing is standing in my bedroom holding a dirt block. I still don 't know what he is or his mechanics. He starts walking away from me but doesn't want to leave. He hasn't attacked so I try to physically push him out the door until finally he teleports. I thought that was it but I was still hearing weird noises. I have a rooftop garden & I found him wandering up there. I'm sick of the sounds he makes & just want him to go away so I attack. He would teleport into the distance & then teleport back but never attack me. I kill him & he dropped xp orbs but nothing good. 
Afterwards I looked him up & his description doesn't at all match how he acted. Survival mode during the day, I was looking right at him the whole time & even attacked but he never attacked back, he just wouldn't leave. Did I get a glitched one?

Comment: Probably. I have had Zombies that just stand there, sometimes in broad daylight! They don't do damage or take damage, but you can destroy your sword on them trying. LOL!

Comment: When endermen are hurt, they prefer teleporting over attacking, I think. Which version are you playing in?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a glitch. Looking at the Enderman's head, or attacking him enrages him. Sometimes the game takes a couple seconds to trigger the aggro mode, but rarely more. Normally Endermen are peaceful, unless you trigger their aggro by the above methods; they can teleport in a rather wide range. They also can't fit into a 2-tall gap, which makes killing them from within a 2-tall shelter quite easy (fighting them in open field is unadvisaed; they hit hard and fast; they are also hurt by water so spilling a water bucket under your feet allows to form a defensive position if you're caught by one in the open.)

They can pick up and place a certain set of blocks (dirt, sand and their variants, netherrack and a couple more); When killed, in 50% cases they drop an Ender Pearl (more when killed with Looting enchanted sword); the Ender Pearls are essential in finding and opening the End portal - so if you plan to reach the endgame content (obtain Elytra and Shulkerboxes) you will have to kill quite a few of them.

Comment: Idk if I picked an unlucky spot for my base but he spawns pretty regularly. Thankfully not inside but I've seen him teleport in the distance. I'll have to try the glitch again when I'm not carrying my good loot.